# unity UI - Carousel menu

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, menu, carousel

I'm trying to make the center button to appear larger than the other buttons in menu selection using unity.

This is how I am spawning the buttons 
`

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfOptions; i++)
   {
   float j = Mathf.Ceil(noOfOptions / 2);
   GameObject newButton =GameObject.Instantiate(buttonToSpawn,this.transform);
   newButton.name = i.ToString() + "Button";
   newButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D = startvector * distanceFromOrigin;
   newButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 2);
    newButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 2);
            newButton.GetComponent<LookAtTest>().index = i;
            //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 45);
            GameObject ChildGameObject1 = buttonToSpawn.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            ChildGameObject1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprites[i];
            startvector = (Quaternion.Euler(0, angleOfDifference, 0) * (startvector)).normalized;

        }

And rotating them in a circular menu : 
 public void RotateScroller()
    {
        print("Rotate");

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, slerpTime * Time.deltaTime);


        if (Mathf.Abs(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y - targetRotation.eulerAngles.y) < 0.1f)
            canRotate = false;

    }
```

`

How can I make the center button appear larger than the rest of the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Group Layout (Vertical or Horizontal)
You can add "Content Size Fitter" to group and change size (or scale, but size is better) of center button

Also you can use scroll view for scrolling and calculate size of buttons with distance from button's position to center of scroll view

Comment: But Iam using Quaternion.Slerp and the menu is infinite,  so any button that comes in the center should be  of a larger size compared to other.Please help me with any links and or tutorials , since Iam new to UI.

Comment: Can you know how many buttons between one button and center?
You can calculate size with this information like scale = maxScale / max(1, amount_from_center)